# Can I default to importing a file sharing its parent directory's name without Webpack?

Tags: javascript, import, create-react-app

I have a project built using create-react-app. When importing, a path will first be checked for a package file, and then for an index file. I am looking for a method to add a further step to this logic. Specifically in the absence of a package or index file, I would like to import from any Javascript file that shares a name with it's parent directory.

For example consider the following project structure:

```
services
    billingService.js
    userService.js
    services.js
app.js
```

If within app.js I performed `import services from './services'` (how I would import currently but not how a solution must necessarily) my desired outcome is a resolution that identifies no `index.js` file is present, and then defaults to returning `services.js`, which shares the name of its parent directory.

I am aware of Webpack plugins that can accomplish this, however as my project is currently built using create-react-app I currently have limited access to Webpack's configuration. I will eject if I have to but first I am keen to explore other options, if any are available.

I would of course also be very interested to know if there is a way to accomplish this in Webpack while using create-react-app that I am unaware of.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions you can provide.

Edit: Added example as requested

Comment: Also, you've mentioned Node, but also Webpack. Are you trying to do this with a Node module you're loading in code that will run in Node, or in a browser module you're loading in code that will run on the browser?

Comment: I am using create-react-app to create a react application, complete with all the Webpack configuration it hides away from you, that will run on the browser. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I'm curious: Why not use the standard `index.js`?

Comment: I have always disliked having multiple files sharing the same name in my projects, and in the case of the standard index.js approach you can quite easily end up with plenty in a moderate sized project. I have always felt having another level to import resolution based on the directory name seemed sensible but am only just exploring options now.

Comment: I'm with you on that one, definitely. It's one of the (many) things I dislike about `npm`.